# My MPI program does not execute properly. MPI_Gather & MPI_Scatter

Tags: c++, c, mpi

```
//Variables for MPI.
    int rc, numtasks, rank;
    int root = 0;
    int tag = 1;
  
    //For the struct.
    MPI_Datatype particletype, oldtype[1]; 
    int blockcounts[1];
    MPI_Aint offset[1];

    //Initialize variables.
    offset[0] = 0;
    blockcounts[0] = 5;
    oldtype[0] = MPI_FLOAT;

//Start MPI.

    rc = MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    if(rc != MPI_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Error starting the MPI program. Terminating. \n");
        MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rc);
    }

    //for (int iteration = 0; iteration < maxIteration; ++iteration)
    //{     
        MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
        MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numtasks);

        if(bodies.size()%numtasks!=0)
            MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1);
        
        //Create Struck.
        MPI_Type_create_struct(1, blockcounts, offset, oldtype, &particletype);
        MPI_Type_commit( &particletype );

        //Scatter variables.
        int count = bodies.size()/numtasks;
        Particle *bufrecv[count];
        Particle *gatherbuf[count];
    Particle bodiess[bodies.size()];  //bodies is a std::vector
    for(int j = 0; j < bodies.size(); j++)
      bodiess[j] = bodies[j];

        MPI_Scatter(bodiess, count, particletype, &bufrecv, count, particletype, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
        
        //ComputeForces(bufrecv, gTerm, deltaT);
        //MoveBodies(bufrecv, deltaT);

        MPI_Gather(&gatherbuf, count, particletype, bufrecv, count, particletype, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        std::cout << "2" << std::endl;

        }

    }*/
    //Finalize MPI.
    MPI_Finalize();
```

//When I execute the program, It never finishes.

```
[sveg0001@grid NBody]$ mpirun -np 4 ./nbody -o input_64.txt
1
1
[grid:10720] *** Process received signal ***
[grid:10718] *** Process received signal ***
1
1
[grid:10717] *** Process received signal ***
[grid:10719] *** Process received signal ***
```

Comment: `bufrecv` has the wrong size (e.g. too small) on the root rank.

Comment: as a matter of style, `MPI_Type_contiguous()` is a better fit that `MPI_Type_create_struct()` here.

Comment: In this case, I am using a vector of particles, and each particle is a struc, How should I create the MPI_Type_contiguous() then? Should I change particle to a vector instead of a struct?

Comment: I do not know how you defined your particle (since you did not post the code). I am just saying `MPI_Type_contigous()` is a better fit (same result but simpler) than `MPI_Type_create_struct()` here.

Comment: Just FYI, unless `MPI_Init()` returns `MPI_SUCCESS`, `MPI_COMM_WORLD` will not be created and hence you cannot call `MPI_Abort()`.